# Merge two Dataset with different column in Spark Structured Streaming JAVA

Tags: spark-structured-streaming

Trying to figure out a way to merge two different dataset to form a combined dataset with all the columns.

```
Dataset<Row> dataActual = rowExtracted.selectExpr(
                "split(value,\"[|]\")[3] as sub_date",
                "split(value,\"[|]\")[7] as status",
                "split(value,\"[|]\")[14] as email_add",
                "split(value,\"[|]\")[15] as source_currency",
                "split(value,\"[|]\")[19] as processing_date"
        );


Dataset<Row> dataStatus = dataActual.select("status").map(
                (MapFunction<Row, String>)row-> mapStatus(row.toString()), 
                Encoders.STRING()).selectExpr("value as txn_latest_status").toDF();
```

Tried using union , join etc but nothing worked

```
    Dataset<Row> data = dataActual.union(dataStatus);
```

Actual:

```
Dataset 1 :
root
 |-- sub_date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- status: string (nullable = true)
 |-- email_add: string (nullable = true)
 |-- source_currency: string (nullable = true)
 |-- processing_date: string (nullable = true)

Dataset 2 :
root
 |-- txn_latest_status: string (nullable = true)
```

Expected result:
Combined Dataset

```
root
 |-- sub_date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- status: string (nullable = true)
 |-- email_add: string (nullable = true)
 |-- source_currency: string (nullable = true)
 |-- processing_date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- txn_latest_status: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: do you have any common column in both the data frames?

Comment: Nope no common column @Ravi

Comment: Please try cross join but the problem is you will have more data due to cross join. Please find the below answer for cross join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the below/

```
scala> res18.show
+-----+
|names|
+-----+
|    A|
|    B|
+-----+


scala> res19.show
+-------+
|numbers|
+-------+
|      1|
|      2|
+-------+
scala>res18.join(res19).show
+-----+-------+
|names|numbers|
+-----+-------+
|    A|      1|
|    A|      2|
|    B|      1|
|    B|      2|
+-----+-------+
```